# function for counting number of times a name appears against a distinct list

Tags: excel

I have a set of 66,000 names, which appear anywhere from 4-31 times. I have created a column of each unique name. I want to check if this unique name appears more than 17 times in my first column.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since you barely give any clear detail of your example excel list (you can create a sample, it doesn't have to be long), this question is liable to downvotes.

Comment: yes I was really lazy and it was a very simple answer lol thank you and I will keep that in mind for future questions I pose!

Comment: Pivot table + filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your list of 66,000 names is in column A and your check list is in column B you could write in C1

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$66000,B1)>17,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: @SamuelDaly simple once you were shown... So use the tick or check mark to accept the answer and even vote it up as well. That is the appreciation system on here.